# Compile sheets and file names into workbook

Tags: excel, vba, automation, filenames, worksheet

I have a master Excel file which will be used as a reference to get the data from different sheet names from different Excel files in a folder,

I've searched the net and could not get a solution. Is there a way to get all the sheet names and paste it per row starting from A2 and A1 and which will reflect its file name without the extension?

Here is what I have so far:

```
Sub SheetNames()

    Columns(1).Insert
    For I = 1 To Sheets.Count
        Cells(I, 1) = Sheets(I).Name
    Next I
End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16901316/how-to-import-data-from-different-excel-files-and-sheets-into-one-main-excel-fil) SO question gives you some code inspiration.

Comment: Jeroen - main objective is to get all the file names and their sheet names.
for example there are 4 files in a folder, their files should be copied and placed per column to the master file, and their respective sheet names per row

A1 = file name 1
A2 = Sheet1
A3 = Sheet2
A4 = Sheet3

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. It will save everything in first sheet of your master workbook:

```
Sub SheetNames()

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim currentWorkbook, wb As Workbook
Dim i, j As Integer

Set currentWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook

'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the current folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(currentWorkbook.Path)
i = 1
j = 2
'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
'we filter filenames, so we get only excel files
'note that second condition is to prevent from using cached workbook associated with opened workbook
'it starts with ~$
If objFile.Name Like "*.xlsx" And Not objFile.Name Like "~$*.xlsx" _
And Not objFile.Name = currentWorkbook.Name Then
    'get the name of a workbook in the first row
        currentWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(1, i).Value = objFile.Name
        'open workbook
        Set wb = Workbooks.Open(currentWorkbook.Path & "/" & objFile.Name)
        'loop through sheets and get their names into cells
        For j = 2 To wb.Worksheets.Count + 1
            currentWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(j, i).Value = wb.Worksheets(j - 1).Name
        Next
        'close workbook without saving changes
        wb.Close (False)
        i = i + 1

    End If

Next objFile

End Sub
```